# Unable to locate element of autocomplete options

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

In my application i have a text box which when i enter the city name brings the city names to
select a city.when i am trying to locate the element,it says it is unable to locate the element.

THis is HTML code

```
<ul id="autocomplete-options-fd419e03-fc56-725a-dc68-0dd3e55a2b19" class="autocomplete-content
dropdown-content" tabindex="0" style="display: block; width: 231.948px; left: 5px; top: 54px; 
height: 50px; transform-origin: 0px 0px; opacity: 1; transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(1);">
<li class="active"><span><span class="highlight">Hyderabad</span></span></li></ul>
```

Here is my script code

```
driver.find_element_by_name('residential_city_id').send_keys("Hyderabad")
tme.sleep(5)
html_list=driver.find_element_by_id("autocomplete-options-fd419e03-fc56-725a-dc68-0dd3e55a2b19")
items = html_list.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
for item in items:
    text = item.text
    print(text)
```

i am getting the following error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate 
element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="autocomplete-options-fd419e03-fc56-725a-dc68-0dd3e55a2b19"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is in these lines of code here:

```
html_list=driver.find_element_by_id("autocomplete-options-fd419e03-fc56-725a-dc68-0dd3e55a2b19")
items = html_list.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
```

The ID `autocomplete-options-fd419e03-fc56-725a-dc68-0dd3e55a2b19` looks like a randomized ID that changes each time you refresh the page. You want to use a more robust selector in this case.

I don't think there is a need to get `items` list at all. I think you can replace the two lines of code above with just one:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Hyderabad']")
```

This will find the `span` element with text `Hyderabad`

Now your code will look like:

```
driver.find_element_by_name('residential_city_id').send_keys("Hyderabad")
tme.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Hyderabad']")
```

Comment: don't use sleeps, use waits.

Comment: I copied sleep from the code posted by the asker. They can change it to wait if they would prefer.

Comment: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"li[text()='Hyderabad']"}
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)

Comment: Updated XPath with `span` instead of `li`, I misread the HTML initially and it looks like the city text is inside the span element.

Comment: still the same exception was coming.unable to locate the element

Comment: @SwarnaMera I updated my XPaths to use `//` notation. Could you try with this: `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Hyderabad']")`

Comment: Thank You Christine,The code was working.I appreciate it.

Comment: @SwarnaMera Glad to hear it. If this solution has helped you, feel free to mark as answer to your question so that other users can see how you resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the *auto complete* element with text as **Hyderabad** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.autocomplete-content.dropdown-content li.active > span > span.highlight"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='autocomplete-content dropdown-content']//li[@class='active']/span/span[@class='highlight' and text()='Hyderabad']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: i tried the code using xpath,i got the following error.